# ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is referenced from these modules with unsupported syntax

Tags: reactjs, webpack, module, babeljs, mobx

In my React + mobx project while building I am getting below warning:

> ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is referenced from these modules
> with unsupported syntax: ./app/containers lazy ^./.*$ namespace
> object (referenced with context element).

This warning is for only some files.

Can anyone explain what this warning actually refer for, if possible provide an example?
Using webpack 4+.

Comment: Same here. For me the Tree Shaking is not happening properly in Webpack and I have spent a lot of time analyzing and trying out... Test Files that I just created and not used anywhere are being added to the bundle.